# Angular child component launch another component which is taken the space as big as parent component

Tags: angular

[image]

A is the left component, B is the right component. C/D/E are a list of card components in B. B is vertical scrollable.

Now what i want to implement is D component button click wants to launch another component(let say Z component) to cover over B component. I don't want B component to be destroyed. I want when Z component close, it can back to B component and show the D component position as previous.

If launch z component directly from D component, I have no idea how to put it to cover over B component.

The idea comes to me is that D component notify B component to launch Z component, then it can put z component in mat-drawer cover over B component. But i don't prefer this way.

Is there any other better way to do?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: lazy load the components on demand.

Answer (score 0):

> The idea comes to me is that D component notify B component to launch Z component, then it can put z component in mat-drawer cover over B component. But i don't prefer this way.

I think this is good. You can go on with it. But as you want alternatives...

##### Alternative 1

You can introduce another Y component to be a parent of both B and Z components. Then when the D component is tapped, it tells the B component, which in turn tells the parent Y component. Y will now make Z show over B. And of course, when Z is closed, it hides out and B shows back.

##### Alternative 2

Use a service for communication between D and Z components. Z component will auto-show if a boolean in that service is true. When Z component closes, it makes the service's boolean false. D component will make this boolean in the service to true (hence showing Z component).

Comment: Thank you. It seems that no easier way to achieve what i want. I will keep my way because it doesn't need extra component or service.